# data received different from data sent through a c sharp socket

Tags: c#, sockets, byte, send

I'm trying to send a file from a client to a server, so I load the file in a byte array in the client side, and send it to the server through the send() method, but the received array is different and bigger than the array sent, I wonder if it's a protocol problem (but I'm using tcp protocol wich assure error detection ):

Client code:

```
IPAddress ipAddress = new IPAddress(ip);
IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 5656);
Socket clientSock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

FileStream fl = File.Open("pos.xls",FileMode.Open);
byte[] fileData = ReadFully(fl);
fl.Close();  

byte[] clientData = new byte[ fileData.Length];
fileData.CopyTo(clientData,0);

curMsg = "Connection to server ...";
clientSock.Connect(ipEnd);

curMsg = "File sending...";
clientSock.Send(clientData);

curMsg = "Disconnecting...";
clientSock.Close();
curMsg = "File transferred.";
```

Server code:

```
curMsg = "Starting...";
sock.Listen(100);

curMsg = "Running and waiting to receive file.";
byte[] clientData = new byte[1024 * 5000];
while (true)
{
    Socket clientSock = sock.Accept();

    clientData = new byte[1024 * 5000];

    int receivedBytesLen = clientSock.Receive(clientData);
    curMsg = "Receiving data...";

    FileStream fz = writeFully(clientData);
    fz.Close();
    curMsg = "Saving file...";
```

Comment: Can you show the different data sent and received please

Comment: have you tried sending a small chunk of known bytes (e.g. new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 } or something) and then comparing to what comes out the other end?  it might point you in the right direction; e.g. is the received size still bigger? if so, is it the same amount bigger as the big file? does the pattern you sent appear somewhere in the output data? etc.

Comment: i'm trying to send an excel file (1.65 MB), i receive a file with 5.12 MB, i'm sure that the problem occurs when the byte array occurs when i'm sending trough the network, because i checked the size of the byte array just before sending and it was good, and just after sending to the server and it changed

Comment: also; not sure if there's a reason for how you are doing it but you can do `byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes("pos.xls");` and there's also an equivalent `File.WriteAllBytes(string path, byte[] bytes);` call.

Comment: ok i will try with small sample of byte, and let you know

Comment: readallbytes() doesn't exist in the compacte framework, sorry i forgot to say that the client is a windows mobile app

Comment: i am just suggesting you send just a few bytes that you know what they are; it may help narrow things down. with that much extra data it almost sounds like something else is sending at the same time; is it possible that you've got multiple threads or copies of your app sending to the same client?  also, you could maybe create a small text file and send that and then save it out and look at it on the other end to see whether it's repeated data or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have *defined* `clientData = new byte[1024 * 5000];` - and you then don't use `receivedBytesLen`. I can't remember whether that `Receive` overload will read *as much as it can until EOF*, or simply "some or EOF" (the latter being the `Stream.Read` behavior), but you *must* verify ***and use*** `receivedBytesLen`.

IMO, the approach of a fixed buffer is inherently flawed, as it doesn't cope well with oversized inputs either. Personally I would use a `NetworkStream` here; then your entire code becomes:

```
using(var fz = File.Create(path)) {
    networkStream.CopyTo(fz);
}
```

Another common approach here is to send the *expected* size as a prefix to the data; that way you can verify that you have the data you need. I personally *wouldn't* use this information to create a correct-sized buffer in memory though, as that still doesn't allow for epic-sized files (a `Stream`, however, does).

Comment: thank you, your answer almost worked, only copyto seems to not existe in the compact framework, so i think it will work if i just write the method by my self, which is not very complicated, thank you

Comment: @Tarik - in that case, loop over with a small buffer into you get something <= 0 from `Read(...)`

Comment: Yes in fact it finally worked, by writing a method similar to CopyTo() , thank you again